# Why jQuery loader not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When my website starts loading it should display loading upto when my website gets loaded. For that I have used jQuery plugin. The following is js file

```
/*
 * jQuery showLoading plugin v1.0
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Jim Keller
 * Context - http://www.contextllc.com
 * 
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 *
 */

    jQuery.fn.showLoading = function(options) {

        var indicatorID;
            var settings = {
                'addClass': '',
                'beforeShow': '', 
                'afterShow': '',
                'hPos': 'center', 
                'vPos': 'center',
                'indicatorZIndex' : 5001, 
                'overlayZIndex': 5000, 
                'parent': '',
                'marginTop': 0,
                'marginLeft': 0,
                'overlayWidth': null,
                'overlayHeight': null
            };

        jQuery.extend(settings, options);

            var loadingDiv = jQuery('<div></div>');
        var overlayDiv = jQuery('<div></div>');

        //
        // Set up ID and classes
        //
        if ( settings.indicatorID ) {
            indicatorID = settings.indicatorID;
        }
        else {
            indicatorID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        }

        jQuery(loadingDiv).attr('id', 'loading-indicator-' + indicatorID );
        jQuery(loadingDiv).addClass('loading-indicator');

        if ( settings.addClass ){
            jQuery(loadingDiv).addClass(settings.addClass);
        }



        //
        // Create the overlay
        //
        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('display', 'none');

        // Append to body, otherwise position() doesn't work on Webkit-based browsers
        jQuery(document.body).append(overlayDiv);

        //
        // Set overlay classes
        //
        jQuery(overlayDiv).attr('id', 'loading-indicator-' + indicatorID + '-overlay');

        jQuery(overlayDiv).addClass('loading-indicator-overlay');

        if ( settings.addClass ){
            jQuery(overlayDiv).addClass(settings.addClass + '-overlay');
        }

        //
        // Set overlay position
        //

        var overlay_width;
        var overlay_height;

        var border_top_width = jQuery(this).css('border-top-width');
        var border_left_width = jQuery(this).css('border-left-width');

        //
        // IE will return values like 'medium' as the default border, 
        // but we need a number
        //
        border_top_width = isNaN(parseInt(border_top_width)) ? 0 : border_top_width;
        border_left_width = isNaN(parseInt(border_left_width)) ? 0 : border_left_width;

        var overlay_left_pos = jQuery(this).offset().left + parseInt(border_left_width);
        var overlay_top_pos = jQuery(this).offset().top + parseInt(border_top_width);

        if ( settings.overlayWidth !== null ) {
            overlay_width = settings.overlayWidth;
        }
        else {
            overlay_width = parseInt(jQuery(this).width()) + parseInt(jQuery(this).css('padding-right')) + parseInt(jQuery(this).css('padding-left'));
        }

        if ( settings.overlayHeight !== null ) {
            overlay_height = settings.overlayWidth;
        }
        else {
            overlay_height = parseInt(jQuery(this).height()) + parseInt(jQuery(this).css('padding-top')) + parseInt(jQuery(this).css('padding-bottom'));
        }


        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('width', overlay_width.toString() + 'px');
        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('height', overlay_height.toString() + 'px');

        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('left', overlay_left_pos.toString() + 'px');
        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('position', 'absolute');

        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('top', overlay_top_pos.toString() + 'px' );
        jQuery(overlayDiv).css('z-index', settings.overlayZIndex);

        //
        // Set any custom overlay CSS       
        //
            if ( settings.overlayCSS ) {
                jQuery(overlayDiv).css ( settings.overlayCSS );
            }


        //
        // We have to append the element to the body first
        // or .width() won't work in Webkit-based browsers (e.g. Chrome, Safari)
        //
        jQuery(loadingDiv).css('display', 'none');
        jQuery(document.body).append(loadingDiv);

        jQuery(loadingDiv).css('position', 'absolute');
        jQuery(loadingDiv).css('z-index', settings.indicatorZIndex);

        //
        // Set top margin
        //

        var indicatorTop = overlay_top_pos;

        if ( settings.marginTop ) {
            indicatorTop += parseInt(settings.marginTop);
        }

        var indicatorLeft = overlay_left_pos;

        if ( settings.marginLeft ) {
            indicatorLeft += parseInt(settings.marginTop);
        }


        //
        // set horizontal position
        //
        if ( settings.hPos.toString().toLowerCase() == 'center' ) {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('left', (indicatorLeft + ((jQuery(overlayDiv).width() - parseInt(jQuery(loadingDiv).width())) / 2)).toString()  + 'px');
        }
        else if ( settings.hPos.toString().toLowerCase() == 'left' ) {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('left', (indicatorLeft + parseInt(jQuery(overlayDiv).css('margin-left'))).toString() + 'px');
        }
        else if ( settings.hPos.toString().toLowerCase() == 'right' ) {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('left', (indicatorLeft + (jQuery(overlayDiv).width() - parseInt(jQuery(loadingDiv).width()))).toString()  + 'px');
        }
        else {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('left', (indicatorLeft + parseInt(settings.hPos)).toString() + 'px');
        }       

        //
        // set vertical position
        //
        if ( settings.vPos.toString().toLowerCase() == 'center' ) {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('top', (indicatorTop + ((jQuery(overlayDiv).height() - parseInt(jQuery(loadingDiv).height())) / 2)).toString()  + 'px');
        }
        else if ( settings.vPos.toString().toLowerCase() == 'top' ) {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('top', indicatorTop.toString() + 'px');
        }
        else if ( settings.vPos.toString().toLowerCase() == 'bottom' ) {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('top', (indicatorTop + (jQuery(overlayDiv).height() - parseInt(jQuery(loadingDiv).height()))).toString()  + 'px');
        }
        else {
            jQuery(loadingDiv).css('top', (indicatorTop + parseInt(settings.vPos)).toString() + 'px' );
        }       




        //
        // Set any custom css for loading indicator
        //
            if ( settings.css ) {
                jQuery(loadingDiv).css ( settings.css );
            }


        //
        // Set up callback options
        //
        var callback_options = 
            {
                'overlay': overlayDiv,
                'indicator': loadingDiv,
                'element': this
            };

        //
        // beforeShow callback
        //
        if ( typeof(settings.beforeShow) == 'function' ) {
            settings.beforeShow( callback_options );
        }

        //
        // Show the overlay
        //
        jQuery(overlayDiv).show();

        //
        // Show the loading indicator
        //
        jQuery(loadingDiv).show();

        //
        // afterShow callback
        //
        if ( typeof(settings.afterShow) == 'function' ) {
            settings.afterShow( callback_options );
        }

        return this;
         };


    jQuery.fn.hideLoading = function(options) {


            var settings = {};

            jQuery.extend(settings, options);

        if ( settings.indicatorID ) {
            indicatorID = settings.indicatorID;
        }
        else {
            indicatorID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        }

        jQuery(document.body).find('#loading-indicator-' + indicatorID ).remove();
        jQuery(document.body).find('#loading-indicator-' + indicatorID + '-overlay' ).remove();

        return this;
        };
```

In html file I used the script as following..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                jQuery('#activity_pane').showLoading(
                    {
                        'afterShow': 
                        function() 
                        {
                            setTimeout( "jQuery('#activity_pane').hideLoading()", 3000 );
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        ); 

</script>
```

and my div tag is as following..

```
<div id="activity_pane">
    Here is where we will load something via ajax.
    <br />
    This container <b>must</b> have an id attribute
</div>
```

but i am getting error as following..

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).showLoading is not a function
function()
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you including Jquery?

Comment: are you loading the jQuery api before your showLoading plugin?

Comment: @ManishMishra: I am using readymade jquery plugin

Comment: Any other js error on page besides that one?

Comment: I knw. see, same thing, all that you have given here, is giving me no error. so you might be calling the libraries in wrong order

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle for us

Comment: @ManishMishra: For that code which is in div tag it works but when I change code in the div tag to my website code it gives that error..

Comment: its pretty simple and neat. make sure, there are no typos and all the required libraries are loaded in correct order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first.

The event below is fired after the whole content is loaded on the page:

```
$(document).ready()
```

So, why would you attach a loading window to this event as it was supposed to be shown while the page gets loaded?

Checking the plugin website, the example given is to attach it to a click event, so the loading window will popup while the AJAX call is being executed.
Unless your whole page is loaded from an AJAX call started on a click event, I'm pretty sure their example wouldn't fit your idea.

Comment: how to do it for page loading?

Comment: @AnandJaju, please refer to this page. It might be what you've been looking for: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-loading-graphic-until-page-fully-loaded/